# CheckBox check state when check

Tags: android

I have this code where when checkBox is checked editTexts gets the time(refreshes when time changes)But when I its unchecked it sets the editText to blank, it doesn't seem to function to what I inteded to do

[image: image link]

```
 check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(check.isChecked()){
                final Handler someHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
                someHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        editTimeOut.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).format(new Date()));
                        someHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    }
                }, 10);
            }
            else{
                editTimeOut.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It looks like it should do what you described.  If you want something else, you need to tell us what you intended.

Comment: I think it should work the way you want with your written code. In else you have written to make edittext blank only.

Comment: it functions correctly when its checked(gets time) but when I uncheck it, it should set the editText the one under time in to nothing

Comment: Maybe try to use the "isChecked" parameter, check.isChecked could be wrong in this moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the edittext every second and not cancelling it. A simple fix is to check if isChecked inside the runnable. A better solution which would need a bit of refactoring would be to remove the runnable.

Simple fix:

```
        if(check.isChecked()){
            final Handler someHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
            someHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(check.isChecked()){
                        editTimeOut.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).format(new Date()));
                        someHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    }
                }
            }, 10);
        }
```

Better fix:

```
final Handler someHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
Runnable timeoutRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    editTimeOut.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).format(new Date()));
                    someHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            };

check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(check.isChecked()){
            someHandler.postDelayed(timeoutRunnable, 10);
        } else{
            someHandler.removeCallbacks(timeoutRunnable);
            editTimeOut.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: np. Glad to help.